# Editing filters in styles for Vector Tiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, mbtiles, openmaptiles

I have got a MbTile with vector tiles with data in the [OpenMapTiles Vector Tile Schema](https://openmaptiles.org/schema/)

When I add it to QGis, I can visualize the data, but the symbology is quite simple.
[image]

I know that I can load a symbology from a JSON file which is in Mapbox GL Style Specification, and the symbology windows shows all the rules, like this:

[image]

How Do I edit these styles? There does not seem to be a way in the QGIS UI to change the Filter for each row, only the Symbol itself can be edited.

Comment: Did you try to open (the JSON file with a text editor to see if it's possible to edit the rule before loading it ?

Comment: While that is possible, I want to know how to edit this in QGIS itself

Answer (score 3):

Click on the desired cell in the "Filter" column, and pressing "F2" on your keyboard. You should be able to edit the cell.